# Why is healthissues.today using my screen 24/7 on my iPhone and how do I stop it?

Tags: iphone

When I checked my screen time it was reporting 24/7 screen for the last 3 weeks.  The offending app is something called healthissues.today which I can't find.  Any ideas on what I can do to turn it off and stop it from using my iphone 24/7?

Comment: If you’re not comfortable posting a screen shot here, maybe a call to Apple support to help narrow down which app you installed has asked for that entitlement? Also when you tap details it should be clear if this is a web page or a proper app.

Comment: 'healthissues.today' purports to be a URL virus scanner. I've never heard of it or its apparent owning company 'Total Scanner'. [This doesn't necessarily imply it's good or bad, but I'd handle with caution].

Comment: Just looked at the site, and it looks *extremely* sketchy. I'd be careful around it, until more research is done for exactly what it is. I tried entering a URL I know to give Malware, and it just directed to a page saying I could buy the domain. Very strange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Evidently (per Apple support) it was a pop-under on Safari that was using a web kit vulnerability to hijack my screen to click jack the site.  Didn't even show in the tab list of Safari.